# Move InfoPath List form template from one environment to another

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

I have created a custom List forms through InfoPath Designer as per the following 
 [article](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Edit-list-forms-using-InfoPath-in-SharePoint-Designer-f86cf514-9a11-4613-a479-12a1a0132d22) from microsoft in my dev environment.

I would like to move this custom list form into further environment like UAT and PROD.

Please suggest an appropriate way to achieve this task.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you are tying the form to a discrete data source so you cant just move the form.  if its relatively simple you can you cut and paste between forms and then just reconnect fields to data points.

if its more complex you need to copy the entire list with the form. i typically like to go beyond ths when crossing farms and actually copy the entire site over.

--Just my 2 cents --

Because there is no future for InfoPath I recommend you look at using SharePoint Designer and customizing the list forms there instead of InfoPath.  The learning curve is higher but it is more flexible and at least for the foreseeable future will upgrade both ob premis and in O365.